# Identify "time out" situation from the server side

Tags: java, client-server, connection-timeout

In a typical client-server architecture, lets say for a particular call from client to server, we've setup a connection timeout as x second. But say for some reason, server took more than x seconds to process the request, so its a timeout for the client, hence the client will no longer listen to the response from the service.

So my question is whether there's any mechanism to identify such a scenario from the service side(that the client is no longer listening to the server response - connection pipe breakdown). If so, can that detection can be done immediately?

Thanks in advance.